# use any unix/linux commands(awk) ,input is like : 78/WESDA.99/C/694883/O///BFPC0T/C/BFPC0T X/C

Tags: awk, sed

use any unix/linux commands(awk) ,input  is like :

```
78/WESDA.99/C/694883/O///BFPC0T/C/BFPC0T   X/C
```

out put should be:

```
78,WESDA.99/C,694883,O,,,BFPC0T,C,BFPC0T   X,C
```

Comment: So what's your question?

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow! To give you a great answer, it might help us if you have a glance at [ask] if you haven't already. It might be also useful if you could provide a [mcve].

Answer (score 0):

you can use one of these;

```
sed 's|/|,|g' yourFile

tr '/' ',' yourFile

awk  '{gsub(/\//,",",$0);print $0}' yourFile
```

Test;

```
$ echo "78/WESDA.99/C/694883/O///BFPC0T/C/BFPC0T   X/C " | sed 's|/|,|g'
78,WESDA.99,C,694883,O,,,BFPC0T,C,BFPC0T   X,C 



$ echo "78/WESDA.99/C/694883/O///BFPC0T/C/BFPC0T   X/C " | tr '/' ','
78,WESDA.99,C,694883,O,,,BFPC0T,C,BFPC0T   X,C
```

Comment: Another fun way with awk: `awk -F/ -v OFS=, '{$1=$1}1'`